# How to apply live() like feature for JavaScript appended DOM elements

Tags: javascript

How to apply `live()` like feature for JavaScript appended DOM elements?

Like a `li` list inside `ul` which is added through JavaScript. I need to do this in plain JavaScript.

Comment: What is "live() like feature"? Is that some jQuery thing you are trying to emulate?

Comment: [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is the doc for .live(). What event are you wanting to bind to with .live()?

Comment: then, throw in a jQuery tag for this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `.live()` is simply event delegation, place your handler on the nearest element to the ones being added.

```
var container = document.getElementById('my_container');

container.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    while(target && target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'LI' ) {
        if( target === this )
            target = null;
        else 
            target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if( target ) {
        // work with the LI
    }
};
```

This is also similar to `.live()` in the sense that it searches from the `e.target` up to the container with the delegate to see if it is your targeted element.

Just testing the `e.target` itself isn't enough if the `li` has descendants.

---

For more complex analysis of the elements, you could use `.matchesSelector`, though you'd need to stick it on the `HTMLElement.prototype` under the correct name, since most browsers include it as an extension.

Also, you'd need a patch for IE8, but that's pretty easy.

```
if (HTMLElement) {
    if (!HTMLElement.prototype.matches && !HTMLElement.prototype.matchesSelector) {
        HTMLElement.prototype.matches =
        HTMLELement.prototype.matchesSelector = 
            HTMLElement.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
            HTMLElement.prototype.mozMatchesSelecvtor ||
            HTMLElement.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
            HTMLElement.prototype.oMatchesSelector;
    }
} else if (!Element.prototype.matchesSelector && Element.prototype.querySelectorAll) {

    Element.prototype.matches = 
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector =
        function() {
            // exercise for reader to implement using .querySelectorAll, 
            //    though it's pretty easy, and available online if you search
        }
}
```

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, the `target &&` test wasn't strictly necessary here since it would `break` at `this`, but I think it's better form to include it, so I threw it in. :)

Comment: Haha it was just funny cause it's over a year old, and the only reason I'm here, and saw that, is because it was linked from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694269/any-emulation-or-alternative-of-live-jquery-function

Comment: @Ian: Ah, I see. I think I'll throw a `matchesSelector` note in there as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind an event to the document root, and check the `event.target` property. If it matches the given selector, then do something.

Example (assuming `addEventListener`)
Example: Match all elements with id `test`:

```
var root = document.documentElement;
root.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target;          // <-- Clicked element
    while (target && target !== root) { // Tree traversing
        if (target.id == 'test') {      // <------ Matches selector
            // Do something.
            break; // Optional: Stop traversal, because a match has been found

        }
        target = target.parentNode; // Go up in the tree
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

the live() is a function of jquery library

```
  .live( events, handler(eventObject) )
```

events: A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as "click" or "keydown." 
As of jQuery 1.4 the string can contain multiple, space-separated event types or custom event names.

handler(eventObject): A function to execute at the time the event is triggered.

for your example, when you created the li inside the ul, you have to you live to capture the li,e.g,

```
$('li').live('mouseover',function(){
   alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: I think it might make more sense to call `live` on the `ul` since that's the persistent parent element.

Comment: The OP wanted to do this in pure JS no outside libs.

Comment: for the ul dont need to use live() since it is created when the html loaded, and i think he is asking for binding events to the newly created one, i.e. li

Comment: @scrappedcola: so his question is confusing? he asked about live() but want only plain javascript! and what point to use js only

Comment: @Skyrel: Not every one wants to use jQuery on every site. OP is asking how to replicate `.live()` behavior without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually attach the event handler whenever you create a new element. Or, you can do it exactly how jQuery is doing it by looking into the jQuery library and extracting the parts you need.