# Any emulation or alternative of live jquery function that addan enent listner for both present and FUTURE elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Any emulation or alternative of live jquery function ?

I need to use an alternative of the live function without JQuery and JQuery.Live.

Especialy that i need to use addEventListner for future elements on the page.

Any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: just add listener to parent and check e.target http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation

Comment: I guess he can't use jQuery? http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation

Comment: Look up the code for `.on()` - Its all open.. :)

Comment: *"I need to use an alternative of the live function **without** JQuery and JQuery.Live."*

Comment: I realy dont need any onther JQuery function. i need an Old school code or another useful function.

Comment: @mplungjan it wont work for FUTUR created elements. the solution staht you recommand work just if the element exist NOW.

Comment: It will work for future elements in the container you attach the event to.

Comment: @MohamedHédiLassoued So use `document` as the container if you don't know of a stable container. In jQuery, you could've used `$("#id").live()`; with the link provided, you'd use: `var container = document;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
var live = function(elm, eventType, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
        if(event.target === elm) {
            callback.call(elm, event);
        }
    });
};
```

You would then use it like follows:

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
live(element, 'click', function() {
  // handle click event here
});
```

**EDIT: Excellent comments below. Here is a revised version:**

```
var live = function(selector, eventType, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
        var elms = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
            target = event.target || window.event.srcElement;
        for (var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
            if (elms[0] === target) callback.call(elms[i], event);
        }
    });
};
```

Use it with css selectors

```
live('#test', 'click', function() {
    // handle click event here
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49aJh/2/

Comment: It's close, but won't target elements properly. Look at the link from the comments on the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198771/how-to-apply-live-like-feature-for-javascript-appended-dom-elements . If you are looking for a specific element, but the event happened in a nested element within it, this won't work. For example, if you wanted to target a `<ul>`, you could click on a nested `<li>`, and the condition would fail. Also, your code assumes the `#test` element is available at all times - you can't do a DOM element reference check - you have to use attributes

Comment: It doesn't work for FUTURE elements created after the Document load. We need a kind callback function that add a listner for any future auto-created elements.

Comment: @Ian - thanks for your (entirely correct) observations. I think the revised version should work better

Comment: Target is : Adding event listeners to current and future elements.

Comment: @MohamedHédiLassoued The revised version works for both current and future elements as requested

Comment: It will add the click listner to all of document elements. Here is an exemple that will popud an alert for all documents clicks but i need to track just google.com link clicks.  var live = function(selector, eventType, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, function(event) {
        var elms = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        for (var i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
               if(elms[i].indexOf('google')!=-1)
            callback.call(elms[i], event)
        }
    });
};
live('a', 'click', function() {
    alert('yes:google');
});

Comment: @MohamedHédiLassoued - fixed error and added a jsFiddle to confirm it works

Comment: Why does it say `if (elms[0] === target)`? Shouldn't it be `if (elms[i] === target)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate the `.on()` functionality with this code:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function (type, selector, func) {
    var attach = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener":"attachEvent",
      elements = this.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this[attach](type, function (e) {
        var target = e && e.target || window.event.srcElement,
           success = false;
        while(target != this){
            console.log("searching"+ target);
            if (contained()){
                success = true;
                break;
            }
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        if(success){func()}
        // helpermethod
        function contained(){ for (var i=elements.length;i--;){ if(elements[i] == target) return true; } }
    });
};

document.querySelector("div").on("click", "span", function() {
    console.log("gotcha!");
});
```

Should work in all browser down to IE8.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RJgaE/6/)**

Comment: Also beware you shouldn't extend the DOM: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: Also note this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/RJgaE/1/

Comment: @Ian I know that article, and I know the caveats but I didn't want to provide a whole wrapper just for demonstration's purposes.

Comment: I understand, I was just providing it as a reference for anyone who sees this

Comment: @Ian but valid point with your second comment, need to check parentElements too...

Comment: Just trying to help get a solid answer :) If it helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198771/how-to-apply-live-like-feature-for-javascript-appended-dom-elements basically does it

Comment: I found the solution here :

Comment: @Ian please have a look at the revised solution;)

Comment: @Mohamed I see no link? Have a look at my revised version.

Comment: This post contain the solution but fire another issue (privacy, External iFrames, ++): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699484/addeventlistner-to-an-iframe-from-different-domain                                                                                       Origin Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198771/how-to-apply-live-like-feature-for-javascript-appended-dom-elements